# Error in segue by calling the same view with 2 button actions

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

I declared the two different push segue in the `myview1` to display the `myview2`.
Two different push segue is called from two different button actions. Its showing the `myview2`.

In `myview2` I am poping the `navigationcontroller` back to the `myview1` in button action.

I am getting error in ios7 but in the previous version of iOS its working:

nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

myview2:

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {

if ([self.addString isEqualToString:@"ADD"]) {
    NSLog(@"11111111add save");
    Xen_ViewController *viewcontroller = [[Xen_ViewController alloc] init];
    DOING some method calling.....
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else if ([self.addString isEqualToString:@"UPDATE"]){
    NSLog(@"222222222update save");
    Xen_ViewController *viewcontroller = [[Xen_ViewController alloc] init];
    DOING some method calling.....
    .....
}
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

myview1:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CallingConfigurationEdit"]){
    //UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    Xen_ConfigurationViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
     controller.addString = @"ADD";
}

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Updation"])
{
    Xen_ConfigurationViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.updateString = self.string;
    controller.addString = @"UPDATE";
}
```

}

How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting that error because you declared two different push segues. There is no need in your case to do that. Declare just one push segue and do not forget to give it an identifier.
I´ve tested your code and works just fine, just keep in mind that whatever method call you perform inside of the if statements of your saveButtonPressed method will end up poping the current viewController and you will get back to you MyView1 controller.

Comment: For edit and update the same screen i am using. for edit button pressed the segue "CallingConfigurationEdit" is called and for update button pressed the segue "Updation" is called. I am having the doubt how to give the single segue for the 2 different button actions. can u help me cesar...thanks in advance.

Comment: you can declare a BOOL property in you destination ViewController and assign a value for that property in your prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender method. Then in the viewDidLoad method of your destination viewController check for that property value and react properly to it.

Comment: thanks cesar i did that only but i for got to delete the other segue..now working fine thanks a lot cesar..once again thankyou very much.

Comment: Hi cesar i getting another problem. four views in my app         view1->view2->view3 its in order..and fourth view i called from the first view(view1->view4)when i poping the segue from the view4 when button pressed the data in the view1 is not displaying and looks empty and any action in view1 app gets terminated and getting error in ios7 only.[ Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'] can you help regarding this...thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly are you doing on view4 ?, do you have a UIButton triggering an action to get back to view1 ?, do you need to pass data back to view 1 ?

Comment: on view1 getting the data from database and by using the data loading the web view in view4 on button action getting back to view1. On view1 viewdidload and viewwillappear method i am getting the data from database.

Comment: you already have your myview1 embeded in a UINvigation controller, haven´t you?. Did you try this in your button action to get back?: [self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];

Comment: thanks cesar s i did in my button action and fixed the issue.i did segue in the interfacebuilder and also thru code also i call the prepareForSegue method and i fixed the issue thanks a lot cesar. can i get ur mail-id to contact u?